# Tomcat Sub Domain Redirection

Tags: tomcat7

I have a domain name registered at a third party hosting site.
The following are the A records I have mapped

```
abc.com     -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.abc.com -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
a.abc.com   -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
b.abc.com   -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is a static IP pointing to my local server at my home. It has a tomcat 7 running on `port 80`. The tomcat has the following in its webapps folder.

```
1. ROOT
2. a
3. b
```

How can I route so that

```
abc.com   opens webapps/ROOT/index.html
a.abc.com opens webapps/a/index.html
b.abc.com opens webapps/b/index.html
```

The local server is running on Cent OS 6.

Answer (score 1):

This has its own documentation chapter called [Virtual Hosting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) in tomcat's documentation.

In short: When you look at your tomcat's server.xml, you'll find an `<Engine>` section, containing a `<Host>` section. By adding more `<Host>` sections and choosing the right domain names, you'll be able to achieve exactly what you want - you'll end up with a slightly different directory structure though.

When you read the documentation, include the comments as they point to some things that could be improved in this documentation.

I sincerely hope that you're not running tomcat as root when it's listening on port 80. In case you do that, I'd change my answer to suggest adding Apache httpd (or equivalent) to the mix, have tomcat listen on its default ports and forward traffic with mod_jk or mod_proxy_jk.